# Application which creates new sets of controls for data

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a C# application, and i'm struggling with the UI side on WPF. The application will recieve new data during runtime, which I need to generate a new set of controls for [(example of the controls)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPCaM.png).

Currently I have this image above set up as a datatemplate, and what i'd like to do is use contentpresenter to create copies, each of which has a different group of data presented. I'm struggling to figure out how to pass different data through to copies created using contentpresenter, instead of just the same values over and over again.

What would be the best method for doing something like this

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Represents a control that can be used to present a collection of
>   items.

and an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) in your ViewModal

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSortOfObservableCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This way you get an updating template repeating list that updates when you add items.

You could also use a `ListBox`, and other things too depending on your needs

Comment: So as I add data to the ObservableCollection it would update during runtime to show the DataTemplate? - that sounds like what i'm after thanks. I'll have a go at trying to implement it, and mark your reply as the answer for now. Thanks